# Deploy standalone database

Tags: database, winforms, deployment, sql-server-2008-r2

I create an application and use SQL SERVER 2008 R2 as its database. How I will deploy my application in a standalone computer without attaching the database? Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Incase you don't want to install sql server on client side,you need  to change database to any document database.you may go for sqlite http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application

Comment: I will start from the scratch again?

Comment: syntax are nearly same as in sql server.study well before making any change.